# Download Multiple Lists

Tags: python, scripting, youtube-dl

I have multiple lists (around 60), and each list contains different URLs sourced from various youtube channels.I want to download them all at once, and each list must move to a separate folder when a list complete.
Is there a premade script for this scenario? I have meager experience in programming.

My current options

```
youtube-dl -f 140 --embed-thumbnail --add-metadata --batch-file=C:\Users\ABC\Downloads\youtube-dl\list_1.txt
```

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40YK0.png)

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for ?

```
# Download videos in separate directory indexed by video order in a playlist
$ youtube-dl -o '%(playlist)s/%(playlist_index)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s' https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLwiyx1dc3P2JR9N8gQaQN_BCvlSlap7re
```

Comment: I mean one list in one folder and another list to another folder, not a youtube playlist.